# Arduino RF signal received but no information being received

Tags: arduino

I am trying to send information through my rf module when I am attempting to send a singal across I am getting information saying that I am getting the singal but I am not getting any information through the line but no information is being passed with it...
   `//Reciever Code (Leonardo)`
    #include

```
void setup()
{
 Serial.begin(9600); 
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(13,LOW);

  vw_setup(2000);
  vw_set_rx_pin(7);
  vw_rx_start();
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println("nothing");
  uint8_t buflen = VW_MAX_MESSAGE_LEN;
  uint8_t buf[buflen];
  if (vw_get_message(buf, &buflen)){
    Serial.print("got it");

    delay(1000);
  }
  if(vw_get_message(buf, &buflen))
  {
    for(int i = 0;i < buflen;i++)

    {
      Serial.println(buf[i]);
      if(buf[i] == '0')
      {
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      }
      else if(buf[i] == '1')
      {
        digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My serial monitor for the reciver reads

`nothing
got it128
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
nothing
got it`

My transmitter code is

```
  #include <VirtualWire.h>

  void setup()
  {

    Serial.begin(9600);

    vw_setup(2000);
    vw_set_tx_pin(7);
  }

  void loop()
  {
    if(1==1)
    {
      char c = '1';

      if(c == '1')
      {
        vw_send((uint8_t *)c, 1);
        Serial.println("SENDING");
      }
      else if(c == '0')
      {
        vw_send((uint8_t *)c, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```

and my modules look like this[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `loop()` function in Arduino runs frequently. There isn't going to be a message received every iteration. For that matter, the sender won't be able to send every loop iteration, either. You can check the return function of the `send()` function to see if the message actually went.

In your receiver code, when you receive a message, you print "got it" correctly. But then you test to see if another message came for turning on an LED. There will not be enough time for the next message to have arrived.

Instead, you should put the printing and LED code in the same `if` block.